# Render Component in All Tab Screens (React-Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have Component with an absolute position and I want it rendered in all Tab Screens.

I tried this but it didn't work

```
<Tab.Navigator
    tabBar={(props) => <CustomBottomNavbar {...props} />}
    initialRouteName="Home"
  >
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Explore" component={Explorer} />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Add"
      component={CreateAd}
      options={{ tabBarVisible: false }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen name="Chat" component={Chat} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={MyAccount} />
    <Feedback />
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

I get error: `A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children`

Is there a way I can achieve this or Should I add it in each individual screen of these components